# asp.net session logout

Tags: asp.net, session, session-timeout

I have made an asp.net application. This application has session variables which shows that a user is logged in or logged out. 
If there any way to capture the expiration of session without going to single pages and once this is logged out user can be redirected to login( Re-login) page?

Can my asp.net classes inherit some base class which can have some abstract method to check if session is existing or not.

Please suggest me some architecture to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global.asax's session end event:

```
void  Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
// your code....
}
```

When the session expire this event called.

Answer (score 2):

> This application has session variables which shows that a user is logged in or logged out.

This can be achieved by checking the `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` property.

> If there any way to capture the expiration of session without going to single pages and once > this is logged out user can be redirected to login( Re-login) page?

Configure the following elements in your applications `web.config` to restrict\allow access to resources\pages\directories on your site:

```
<authorization> 
   <allow .../>
   <deny .../>
</authorization>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t

And, configure the `FormsAuthentication` [defaulturl and loginurl attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61) to redirect users away from restricted resources.